# Creating an Array of Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Working on an Assignment and I am trying to create an Array of Pointers to the person object as stated in the brief...

> Add code to your main method to enable you to create 3 (or more) Person 
>   objects, store pointers to them in an array of pointers to Person, and order them 
>   alphabetically

However I can only create pointers to their sub class as I believe you can't instantiate an abstract class, is this correct? my code so far is below

```
Person *personArray[3]; //pointers to person objects

personArray[0] = new Employee("Bill", 1200);
personArray[1] = new Customer("Steve");
personArray[2] = new Employee("Bill", 1200);
```

Employee and Customer are sub classes of Person

Thanks!

Comment: Well, did you try compiling and running it?

Comment: And you should also post the code for that 'abstract class' you were talking about... and what do you want to order alphabetically.. person names?

Comment: Based on the requirements you listed, this looks right. If both `Employee` and `Customer` are subclasses of the abstract `Person` class, this is how I would do that.

Comment: There is no problem by making a base class pointer to point to a derived class object

Comment: But note that the assignment does not require you to allocate the Person objects dynamically.

Comment: Yeah it compiles no problem, i just wasn't sure what was meant in the brief. Yeah i have to sort them by the persons names using overload operators and the compare method.

Comment: @juanchopanza But since the base class is abstract, its the only way to create objects of it and point them to derived classes!

Comment: @nitish712 Yes, and? It still doesn't mean you have to instantiate the objects dynamically.

Comment: @juanchopanza well I would say its a general method used in these scenarios AFAIK..:)

Comment: @nitish712 I am just stating a fact. I don't want to speculate about general methods in certain scenarios that are not at all clear.

Comment: So you understand that you can instantiate a `Person*`, and have it point to an `Employee`. What's your question?

Comment: Tell your instructor to use `std::vector` instead of an array, they are safer.

Comment: @Beta my question although i didn't really word it this way was, is it at all possible to instantiate the abstract class Person and not its sub classes?

Comment: No, it isn't. And if that's your question, it shouldn't have the title "Creating an Array of Pointers".

Comment: yep my bad, apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Vector.

```
#include<vector>

class Person{};
class Employee:public Person{};
class Man: public Person{};

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    Employee* emp = new Employee;
    std::vector<Person*> people;
    people.push_back(new Employee);
    people.push_back(new Person);
    people.push_back(new Man);
    people.push_back(emp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it has to be an array, also how would one go about sorting the array of classes by name?